# Adding an image from a document tab to email template?

Tags: visualforce, email-template, images

I have many images in document tab and all are externally available. When I try to add the image in HTML & VF email template, the images look broken in outlook when its received.

[image]

I thinks thats a minor error that's causing this. Any help is appreciated.

```
<messaging:emailTemplate subject="Details -" recipientType="User" relatedToType="Evaluation__c">
<messaging:plainTextEmailBody>

    Congratulations! This is your new Visualforce Email Template. Hello, Sample Image below: <br/>
    <apex:image url="https://aec.cs51.content.force.com/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=0254B0000000WmD" />

</messaging:plainTextEmailBody>
</messaging:emailTemplate>
```

**Note:** When the url is opened in different browser, it requires login.

Comment: this link might be helpful for adding an image from a document tab https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000gq6EAAQ http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=email_template_images.html

Comment: Trying. Meanwhile, is it ok for images in any folder? Or it must be in the shared documents folder?

Comment: There should be a Documents tab in your Salesforce.com org. If not select the + at the right of the tabs and select the Documents link. Upload you image to a folder of choice (be sure not to upload to Personal Folder)

Comment: @AmitJain it can be in personal folder

Answer (score 5, accepted):

open document tab,and image what u want to display,right click on image copy and paste it in `<apex:image >`

```
<messaging:emailTemplate subject="vf template" recipientType="Contact" >   
   <messaging:plainTextEmailBody >
    Congratulations! This is your new Visualforce Email Template. 
    <apex:image url="sahitya0907-dev-ed--c.ap2.content.force.com/servlet/…; /> 
</messaging:plainTextEmailBody> </messaging:emailTemplate>
```

Comment: <messaging:emailTemplate subject="vf template" recipientType="Contact" >
<messaging:plainTextEmailBody >
Congratulations!
This is your new Visualforce Email Template.
<apex:image url="https://sahitya0907-dev-ed--c.ap2.content.force.com/servlet/servlet.ImageServer?id=015280000003lDF&oid=00D280000019aDw&lastMod=1453885520000" />

</messaging:plainTextEmailBody>
</messaging:emailTemplate>

Answer (score 4):

You need to pass organization id while referring externally available image in your email document and url is also bit different which you use while referring the document.

```
<messaging:emailTemplate subject="Details -" recipientType="User" relatedToType="Evaluation__c">
<messaging:plainTextEmailBody>

    Congratulations! This is your new Visualforce Email Template. Hello, Sample Image below: <br/>
    <apex:image
    url="https://aec.cs51.content.force.com/servlet/servlet.ImageServer?id=0254B0000000WmD&oid=YOURORGID" />

</messaging:plainTextEmailBody>
</messaging:emailTemplate>
```